# What Linux distributions come with Python 3 as the default?

Tags: linux, python, python3

I know that ArchLinux has Python 3 as the default Python install. What other Linux distributions ship with Python 3 as the default Python version?

I've checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127715/is-there-any-linux-distribution-that-comes-with-python-3), but it seems more geared towards answering "what distributions have Python 3 packages available?"

Comment: The fact Arch has python3 as the default doesn't mean much as most stuff is still built against python2 for the simple reason upstream has not ported the code to py3k. That being said, if you're looking for a python3 only environment I suggest you install gentoo and try to build everything against python3. Some stuff would break though... Also, I hear the next Ubuntu will come with python3 as the default...

Comment: That's actually the reason for my question; I know a lot of stuff hasn't been ported, and I run a large infrastructure in Python that does a lot of automated package management, and I want to test if it works in a system that has python3 as the default "python" packaging name (as opposed to "python3"), and test some other compat stuff.

Comment: Lubuntu 12.10 also comes with Python 3.2 by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arch and Gentoo have python 3 as system default, that is when you `pacman -S python` or `emerge dev-lang/python` you will get python 3.* and that will be the target for `/usr/bin/python`